# How do I pull up the Expo QR code after React Native app has been started?

Tags: react-native, expo, okta

I've already started the app and did not see the QR code on the initial terminal after CRNA set up. 
How can I pull it up now to scan the code?

Answer (score 1):

Simply type "q" in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

you can shake the device and get a link to copy paste for someone else. Otherwise would recommend just restarting the packager to get the code.

Comment: I'm trying to pull up the qr code to connect the device, so it's not on the device already and shaking it would be futile.